# Calling all instances of all child classes with the parent class

Tags: class, inheritance

Say you have 3 child classes, for example

```
Class Dog{
void ageDog(){
age+=7;
}
}

Class Cat{
void ageCat(){
age +=5;
}
}

Class Hamster{
void ageHamster(){
age+=20;
}
}
```

Right now I have it written so that an instance of each class is declared and called inside a function

```
agePets(){
dog.ageDog();
cat.ageCat();
hamster.ageHamster();
}
```

How do you create a parent class with an age pets function

```
class Pets{
 //age pets()
}
```

and rewrite the function so that it won't have to be changed even if there is more than one instance of a class or other child classes are written (for example class Bird or something)
I know implementation involves inheritance but I'm not sure how to implement it
Disclaimer: This is psuedo code

Comment: What language? None of this looks valid in any language I know.

Comment: What are these supposedly "child classes" supposed to be children of? Where does `age` come from?

Comment: It's pseudo code, and each animal class i wanted to be the child class of class pets, with a single method that could call each instance of each child class. I eventually determined the best way to do this was with an arraylist of pets and calling agePets() on each pet in the arraylist

Answer (score 0):

```
class Animal {
    protected void age(int amount) {
        age+=amount;
    }
    int age;
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    void age() {
        age(5);
    }
}
class So41646958 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Cat cat=new Cat();
    cat.age();
    System.out.println(cat.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Up until the last class thing you put in, I totally understand this. I'm not positive what language your writing in, which might be the problem, but i just needed a way to write a function that called the age function on every instance of every child class

Comment: it's java. the last class is just a god class to exercise the system. if you want to age every instance, you will have to keep track of all of the instances somehow.